# What is the purpose of using <link rel="url" href="https://example.com"/> in the head of a web page?

Tags: html

I've was examining the meta tags of one of my competitors and noticed the following line at the very beginning of the head of their page. It had the url of the page that the tag was on.

**Does anyone know why it would be included in the head of a page? What is its purpose?**

I've Googled  many times and have searched for it in as many forums as possible but do not get any matches. I get matches for  but not for .

I also searched on this website but didn't find any matches here either.

Comment: It looks like a mistake. Here are the [valid rel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel) - they likely wanted "canonical"

Comment: Note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob XHTML requires it. Don't you consider XHTML to be HTML?

Comment: @RoToRa The question is tagged HTML. XHTML is HTML reformulated as XML, thus the reason for the closing slash in that. This is not XHTML.

Comment: ....after all, that's a strange hint. Should the OP now report this to their competitor? How does that change the meaning of this question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is probably a error. What he should use is:
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com"/>`

But even than I dont know if your competitor is running domain example.com, co it is probably some copy paste mistake.

Canonical urls are used for example if your site has some product lists that can be sorted like this:

```
example.com/product123
example.com/product123?sort=name
example.com/product123?sort=id
example.com/product123?sort=price
```

But in fact all of those pages refer to the same content. By using `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/product123"/>` you tell search engines that this is the page to prioritize in results

Comment: Note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.